# how to get extract object from json result in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, json.net, json

I put data table into `json` string using `newtonsoft json`. this is part of the result  string,

```
[{"SHIP-CD;SHIP-NAME;CABIN NUMBER;CATEGORY CODE;CATEGORY DESC;MIN OCCUPANCY;MAX OCCUPANCY;PHYSICALLY CHALLENGED;DECK CODE;DECK DESC;START DATE VALIDATION;END DATE VALIDATION;OBS-VIEW;BED-ARRMNT;":"AR;MSC ARMONIA;9152;B2;Balcony Fantastica;1;3;no;AMET;Ametista;14/03/16;31/03/17;NO;L:2|U:1;"},{"SHIP-CD;SHIP-NAME;CABIN NUMBER;CATEGORY CODE;CATEGORY DESC;MIN OCCUPANCY;MAX OCCUPANCY;PHYSICALLY CHALLENGED;DECK CODE;DECK DESC;START DATE VALIDATION;END DATE VALIDATION;OBS-VIEW;BED-ARRMNT;":"AR;MSC ARMONIA;9189;B2;Balcony Fantastica;1;3;no;AMET;Ametista;14/03/16;31/03/17;NO;L:2|U:1;"},
```

how can I extract objects ,data from this.it comes all together.as an example think about below

```
{"SHIP-CD;SHIP-NAME;CABIN NUMBER;CATEGORY CODE;CATEGORY DESC;MIN OCCUPANCY;MAX OCCUPANCY;PHYSICALLY CHALLENGED;DECK CODE;DECK DESC;START DATE VALIDATION;END DATE VALIDATION;OBS-VIEW;BED-ARRMNT;":"AR;MSC ARMONIA;9189;B2;Balcony Fantastica;1;3;no;AMET;Ametista;14/03/16;31/03/17;NO;L:2|U:1;"}
```

in above part

```
SHIP-CD :"AR",
SHIP-NAME:"MSC ARMONIA",
```

like that. please help me with this.

Comment: So you are getting data from somewhere in that format or are you putting it in that format? Not sure also what you mean by extracting objects?

Answer (score 0):

Bill, I would recommend to change the way you put data into json. In the way you do it, you have the same key multiplied by the number of entries you get instead of having the key only one time.

Also, why not try to split the key components? In this way you don't have to process strings and you can easily translate them into a dictionary.

```
"array": [
    {
        "SHIP-CD": "AR;MSC ARMONIA",
        "SHIP-NAME": "MSC ARMONIA",
        "CABIN NUMBER": 9189,
        "..."
    },
    {
        "SHIP-CD": "AR;MSC ARMONIA",
        "SHIP-NAME": "MSC ARMONIA",
        "CABIN NUMBER": 9189,
        "..."
    },
    ...
]
```